# How can I build a Kentico media selector to return media file GUID when integrating with Azure storage?

Tags: azure, kentico

We have a Kentico 9 instance with media library integrated with Azure blob storage. This means that Kentico's default media selector form control returns an absolute URL of the Azure blob. However, as well as the URL, I need to access the media file info object itself to get additional properties (such as file width).

In the past when using Kentico's own file storage I've been able to build a custom media selector and pull the media file GUID from the returned URL. However, this isn't possible when integrating with Azure storage. Does anyone have any ideas how I might get the file ID or GUID without building my own media selector from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

How about using custom form control with an [UniSelector](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/UniSelector) control to which you would pass **all files** from your azure media library?

You could get the files using something like:

```
        var mediaLibrary = MediaLibraryInfoProvider.GetMediaLibraryInfo("MyAzureLibrary", "SiteName");
        var mediaFiles = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFiles()
            .Columns("FileName", "FilePath", "FileGUID")
            .WhereEquals("FileLibraryID", mediaLibrary.LibraryID);
```

This way you could get "nice" dialog that would list all the files in particular folder and you could set up the UniSelector to store **GUIDS** of those files instead of their paths.

The disadvantage of this is that you don't get the nice tree view as you do in Media library. Once you have the GUID of file, you can then reconstruct the full absolute URL.

If you wanted to have the tree view you could use the [CMSTreeView](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/CMSTreeView) control, but it is more complicated and you would probably need to place it inside a modal window so that it doesn't overflow with other content. Modifying the built-in MediaSelector form control is not really possibly because its under the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @enn but really I think any media selector needs thumbnail previews to be truly effective. Also, in my case user will need to be able to switch libraries and, potentially, sites so uni selector isn't powerful enough sadly. It would seem a full custom form control is necessary. It does bother me how limited Kentico's media functionality is :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the following setting:

Content -> Media -> Security -> Check files permissions

In that case inserted media URLs should remain as permanent URLs (because the media handler needs to check the permissions) and you should be able to extract the GUID from the URL as you are used to.